# Unable to refresh to DataTable after executing ajax using PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to refresh DataTable after the add operation but it doesn't work.
below is my code.

this code is generated using netbeans jsf entity classes from database.
im sure that all the code below are executed successfully without any error.

javascript code

```
 function update(){
       updateComment();
    }
```

view.xhtml

```
<h:form id="commentArea">
              <!--for Comment Area-->
             rendered="#{issueCommentController.items.rowCount == 0}" style="padding-bottom: 10px;"/><br/>
              <h:panelGroup>
                <h:dataTable id="commentTable" value="#{issueCommentController.getCommentModel(issueController.selected.id)}" var="comment" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" rules="all">
                  <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="Comment"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{comment.comment}"/>
                  </h:column>
                  <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="Comment Date"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{comment.commentedDate}">
                      <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                  </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
              </h:panelGroup>
              <h:inputTextarea id="reply-thread-txt" value="#{issueCommentController.selected.comment}"></h:inputTextarea>
              <div style="clear:both"></div>
              <div class="padding-top-10" style="width:284px !Important; margin-top: 10px;">
<p:remoteCommand name="updateComment" action="#{issueCommentController.retrieveComment(issueController.selected.id)}" update="commentArea"/>
                <p:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" oncomplete="update();" value="Reply" action="#{issueCommentController.create}">
                  <f:param name="issue.id" value="#{issueController.selected.id}"/>
                  <f:param name="commented.by" value="#{sessionScope.LOGIN_USER}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
              </div>
            </h:form>
```

IssueCommentController.java

```
public DataModel getCommentModel(int id){
    if(commentModel == null){
      commentModel = getCommentPagination(id).createPageDataModel();
    }
    return commentModel;
  }

//comment pagination.
public PaginationHelper getCommentPagination(final int id) {
    if (commentPagination == null) {
      commentPagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
        @Override
        public int getItemsCount() {
          return getFacade().count();
        }

        @Override
        public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
          return new ListDataModel(getFacade().getComment(id));
        }
      };
    }
    return commentPagination;
  }
//execuate query
 public List<IssueComment> getComment(int id){
    TypedQuery<IssueComment> tq = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT c FROM IssueComment AS c WHERE c.issueId=:id",IssueComment.class);
    Issue issue = new Issue(id);
    tq.setParameter("id", issue);
    return tq.getResultList();
  }
//execute after the add operation using ajax.
 public void retrieveComment(int id) {
    items = getCommentPagination(id).createPageDataModel();
  }
```

after the add operation this will be executed.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateComment" action="#{issueCommentController.retrieveComment(issueController.selected.id)}" update="commentArea"/>
```

but it doesnt refresh the datatable.

anyhelp would be appreciated.
thnks.

Comment: `rendered="#{issueCommentController.items.rowCount == 0}"` belongs to what element in your view? And why the roundtrip between `update()` and `updateComment`? You *are* aware that you can directly reference `updateComment` from the command button, instead of the needless js?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to edit that one. supposed to be it's rendered="#{issueCommentController.getCommentModel(issueController.selected.id)==0}". and about that update() and updateComment, I used another js to call updateComment cause I am planning to add a modal before calling the it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem but I'll post my answer in case it may help to others.
I replaced remoteCommand code from this.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateComment" action="#{issueCommentController.retrieveComment(issueController.selected.id)}" update="commentArea"/>
```

to this.

```
 <p:remoteCommand name="updateComment" action="#{issueCommentController.getCommentModel(issueController.selected.id)}" update="commentArea"/>
```